# Resolve error in creating table of logit regression results with stargazer in R

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, logistic-regression, stargazer

I am hoping to present a nice table of a logistic regression measuring hypertension using stargazer which includes the coefficients, standard error, and significance (indicated  by stars). When I try and plug in the specifications for stargazer, I see the following error message: "% Error: Unrecognized object type." I've included some sample data/the code I've run below. How might this be resolved? Thank you!

```
library(stargazer)
library(mfx)

structure(list(AGE = c(40L, 23L, 24L, 18L, 30L, 33L, 32L, 63L, 
22L, 24L), IMMIGRANT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), FAMSIZE = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), HLTH_INS = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), HYPERTEN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    SMOKE = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), PSU = c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

#The regression works without adjusting for clustered SE 
logit<-logitmfx(HYPERTEN~AGE+IMMIGRANT+FAMSIZE+HLTH_INS+
                 SMOKE,data=sample,
                atmean=TRUE,robust=T)

logit_mfx_coef <- logit$mfxest[,1]  
logit_mfx_se <- logit$mfxest[,2] 

stargazer(logit, type="text",title = "Predicting Probability of Hypertension",intercept.bottom=FALSE,
          coef = logit_mfx_coef,
          se   = logit_mfx_coef, column.labels="Logit mfx",
          digits=4,align=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `logit$fit` as the first argument to `stargazer()`.

The [`logitmfx()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mfx/versions/1.2-2/topics/logitmfx) operation returns a bunch of stuff, but [`stargazer()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stargazer/versions/5.2.2/topics/stargazer) expects a fitted model object (or a data frame) as its first argument.

```
stargazer(logit$fit, type="text",title = "Predicting Probability of Hypertension",intercept.bottom=FALSE,
          coef = logit_mfx_coef,
          se   = logit_mfx_coef, column.labels="Logit mfx",
          digits=4,align=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
Predicting Probability of Hypertension
=============================================
                      Dependent variable:    
                  ---------------------------
                           HYPERTEN          
                           Logit mfx         
---------------------------------------------
Constant                    0.0000           
                           (0.0000)          
                                             
AGE                                          
                                             
                                             
IMMIGRANT                                    
                                             
                                             
FAMSIZE                                      
                                             
                                             
HLTH_INS                                     
                                             
                                             
SMOKE                                        
                                             
                                             
---------------------------------------------
Observations                  10             
Log Likelihood              -0.0000          
Akaike Inf. Crit.           10.0000          
=============================================
Note:             *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: yay it ran! Thanks so much.